# In STIX, what are the differences between tools, infrastructure, and malware

Tags: terminology

I am starting to learn STIX, and the exact meaning of some of the SDOs is not really clear to me.

In particular, can someone give precise guidelines or examples of the differences between the ***tool***, ***infrastructure***, and ***malware*** SDOs?

Naively, I understand that:

- ***malware*** = a software package that does harm
- ***infrastructure*** = software or hardware that either aids a malware attack or is part of the defense against it
- ***tool*** = software that has a legitimate purpose, but can also be used as part of a malware attack

But, there are obvious overlaps between these definitions, as well as uncovered gaps between them, so I assume that my naive definitions are not quite correct.

The formal definitions at https://oasis-open.github.io/cti-documentation/stix/intro don't quite help me -- they are how I arrived at my naive definitions above.  What are crisper definitions, or examples that illustrate the edge cases?

Comment: Your re-telling of the words from the link are fine. What's your struggle? Why do you think that the definitions are not correct? Yes there are overlaps, but that would be expected. Why are the overlaps a concern? "Poodles and dogs" and all that. I'm afraid that any answer will repeat what you already have.

Comment: Have you looked at the vocabularies on the same page for examples: https://docs.oasis-open.org/cti/stix/v2.1/cs01/stix-v2.1-cs01.html

Comment: Thanks!
Overlaps are a concern because I'm collecting and annotating training examples to build an NLP model of STIX relationships. I realize that there are always fuzzy cases, but I'd like to minimize them. I'm going to need to draw a line between between, e.g., tools and infrastructures. Wherever I put the line, my models will still be self-consistent; so the exact placement doesn't matter much for my internal purposes.
But, for the sake of interop with other tools and taxonomies, I'd rather come as close as possible to accepted conventions.

Comment: Re the vocabularies. Yes, I've looked at them in chapter 10 of the document. They are excellent for malware, and have some info for infrastructure. But, I did not see anything for tool, nor enough to get a good instinct for any of the three borders between the categories.

Actually, what would really help me -- almost as much as more detailed definitions -- would be multiple examples of STIX documents using these SDOs. Unfortunately, I've found very few STIX samples so far.

Comment: If you are training NLP models, you will have great difficulty. As structured as STIX is, it's still only very fuzzy. Remember hat "infrastructure" also includes the "target". If you want to train models, you will have to omit some of these terms because they are truly undefined.

Comment: So ... your question does not quite reflect your situation. These terms are clear *for you*. But your models are unclear. That's a different problem. Any examples we can provide won't accurately reflect the feeds you end up parsing. You have a taxonomy problem, not a terminology problem.

Comment: Agreed 100%.  I've over-simplified to get a small enough question to make sense on StackExchange.

I intend to ignore most of the STIX SDOs, and I intend to define entities in a way that works well for this project.

From my POV, I don't care if my supporting tools are called "tool" or "infrastructure" or even "Santa Claus", nor if I divide software into two entity classes or three.

But, if there are existing example sets or edge-case definitions, then I'd rather copy them and not re-invent.

However, it sounds like you are saying that there are none, so...

Comment: From experience, different sources can and will use the different taxonomies differently. And the taxonomies themselves are only loosely defined. Realities of threats are difficult to classify especially when the classification might change based on perspective and context. Like a modular ransomware that can become infrastructure as needed for further infiltration into segmented networks.